# Is this to be an English-only site?

Tags: discussion, scope, on-topic

Language learners come from all over the world. In a perfect world, all of them would be able to ask questions on Language Learning. On the other hand, having questions in any language imaginable might be unfeasible. It could be hard to find questions in your language (though we could use tags for the language used in the question), it could be difficult to find duplicates (they may be spread among several languages), and for languages with fewer online-representatives, it might be difficult to obtain answer-ers competent in the language.

One compromise might be to allow any language, given a translation into English by a member of the community within a given time frame. If no translation is given by the end of the time frame, the question is closed.

What should the site policy for this be? English only, all languages, all languages with translations, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Yes

The site should be in English. SE is an English-speaking site, we are an English-speaking community. Splintering discussions by allowing posts in other languages will hurt, not help the community grow.

This does not mean that all posts ought to be in ASCII*, and that foreign words shouldn't be used in examples.

*If you think proper English is always ASCII, you're sadly naïve.

Comment: Are you saying all questions should be about learning english or posts should be written in english? Clarify that, and I'll upvote this answer.

Comment: I'm saying all posts need to be written in English. That's what the question is asking about, so that's the question I answered. If the question is "can we talk about learning other languages?" the answer is an obvious "yes." Otherwise we'd be called [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).