# Como eu posso dizer a palavra "obrigado" na lingua Esloveno (slovenščina)?

Tags: discussion

I hope I do not offend anyone and I do not even seem like a provocateur for the question that I will ask ...

It would be off-topic if I post my future questions on this site in my native language, in this case, Portuguese.

**Example:**

> Como eu posso dizer a palavra "obrigado" na lingua Esloveno (slovenščina)?

With this question, I will give the **answerer** an opportunity to learn a new language...

Or we should use a standard language, in this case, English language as is customary.

It's just a proposal and an idea. The English language for me is very valid.

Comment: The question what language the site should be in has already been answered here: [Is this to be an English-only site?](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13/800).

Comment: Forgive me for being indiscreet. I saw your profile and I do not know what the terms C2, C1 / C2, HSK3, ...

Comment: C1, C2 etc. are levels defined in the [CEFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages); [HSK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanyu_Shuiping_Kaoshi) is a Chinese proficiency test.